# Why does the ICPS carry extra hydrogen?

Tags: sls, artemis-program, delta-iv, artemis-1

The Interim Cryogenic Propulsion Stage (ICPS) of the Space Launch System is essentially the Delta Cryogenic Second Stage (DCSS) lifted from the Delta IV rocket. However, among other minor changes, the ICPS features most notably a stretched LH2 tank.

However, there is no corresponding increase in the amount of oxidiser being carried. Is it to allow for some boil off while loitering in Earth orbit or is there another reason?

https://blog.ulalaunch.com/blog/icps-1-stage-stacked-atop-first-sls-rocket

Comment: For safety in case something goes wrong making it need extra fuel @Andykins

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Why didn't they protect against something going wrong that makes it need more oxygen?

Comment: Because rockets tend to have a Oxygen:Propellant ratio over 1. Therefore it would take up more mass @OrganicMarble

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Oxygen is a propellant.

Comment: Do you have a source giving the hydrogen and oxygen tankage capacities for DCSS-5 and for ICPS?

Comment: By propellant I mean not oxider @OrganicMarble

Comment: No. Try to find me a single rocket with more propellant than oxidizer. That is a source @RussellBorogove

Comment: All liquid-fueled rockets have more propellant than oxidizer, because oxidizer is a propellant. Propellant = oxidizer + fuel

Comment: I have defined propellant as the whats in tha tanks that isnt oxidizer. @OrganicMarble

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch unfortunately you don't get to define that. Despite what you and Humpty Dumpty think, words have actual meanings. Especially in engineering.

Comment: Okay. That is correct. What I meant to say was that a rockets Oxidizer:Fuel ratio is nearly always over 1 @OrganicMarble

Comment: Why are you copping attitude, Starship? I was asking OP what the actual proportions of hydrogen and oxygen were so I could work out the actual mixture ratios of DCSS and ICPS. RL10 can operate over a wide range of mixture ratios.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I had the same thought, but at least based on Wikipedia, the DCSS and ICPS use the same version of the RL10.